# Error en la paginación de Cards en Vue y Vuetify, problema con v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Realizando una aplicación con Vue y Vuetify donde genero v-cards según un array de objetos, sin realizar la paginación de los v-cards no tengo problema, ya que el v-model lo construyo con el mismo array su índice, ahora al agregar la paginación, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```html
<v-col v-for="(item,index) in pagProductes" cols="12" xs="6" sm="6" md="3" xl="3" lg="3">
  <v-card>
    <v-img :src="pathImage(item.imatge)"></v-img>
    <v-card-title class='pb-0'>{{item.nom}} - {{item.preu}}€</v-card-title>
    <v-card-subtitle class='my-0 py-0'>Categoria: {{item.categoria}}</v-card-subtitle>
    <v-card-text class='mt-0 py-0'>Ref: {{item.referencia}}</v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions class='mt-4 py-0'>
      <v-text-field outlined v-model='pagProductes[index].qini' label='Quantitat' placeholder="Quantitat"></v-text-field>
      <v-btn icon color='grey' @click="afegiralcarret(index)"> <v-icon> mdi-cart</v-icon></v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</v-col>

//Para crear la navegación de la paginación

<div class="text-center">
  <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="long" :total-visible="long"></v-pagination>
</div>
```

Con la propiedad computada pagProductes:

```html
pagProductes() {
  const number = 8;
    return this.cataleg.slice((this.page - 1) * number, this.page * number);
}
```

Como en cada página tengo 8 v-cards, cuando voy seleccionando con el método afegiralcarret(index), en la primera página no tengo problema, pero por ejemplo al seleccionar el v-card 20 (el 4 de la tercera página) vuelve a seleccionar el v-card 4, que es el index 4.

He pensado en generar una propiedad computada para crear el índice de v-model tal que así:

```html
productIndex(index){
  //this.long = 8
  return (this.page-1)*this.long + index;
}
```

Y con esto en el v-model del v-for hacer:

```html
<v-text-field outlined v-model='pagProductes[productIndex].qini' label='Quantitat' placeholder="Quantitat"></v-text-field>
```

Pero obtengo un error, donde me indica que qini no está definido,el índice no es correcto, ¿cuál sería la manera correcta de calcular este index y poder crear el v-model de la forma correcta?

Comment: ¿Cómo generas `this.cataleg`? Podrías agregar la propiedad `index` a cada elemento y no usar la posición del arreglo, porque [array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) te devuelve un **nuevo** arreglo, con sus propios índices.

Comment: Genero this.cataleg con una llamada fetch, obtengo un json. Con el slice se generan nuevos índices, he pensado en crear el v-model, a partir de la referencia y guardar ahí la cantidad.

Comment: He resuelto el problema como has comentado Triby.

Comment: ¡Excelente! Sería bueno que publiques la respuesta con la solución (código), así otros usuarios con el mismo problema sabrán qué hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la idea de Triby, he generado un array con el índice del producto, y en lugar de utilizar this.cataleg para el v-model que utilizaba en la paginación utilizo este nuevo array. El problema lo tenía que al realizar la paginación (con slice) el índice del array cambiaba. Con esto:

```html
<v-col v-for="(item,index) in pagProductes" :key='item.id' cols="12" xs="6" sm="6" md="3" xl="3" lg="3">
  <v-card>
    <v-img :src="pathImage(item.imatge)"></v-img>
    <v-card-title class='pb-0'>{{item.nom}} - {{item.preu}}€</v-card-title>
    <v-card-subtitle class='my-0 py-0'>Categoria: {{item.categoria}}</v-card-subtitle>
    <v-card-text class='mt-0 py-0'>Ref: {{item.referencia}}</v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions class='mt-4 py-0'>
      <v-text-field outlined v-model='ncataleg[item.id].qini' label='Quantitat' placeholder="Quantitat"></v-text-field>
      <v-btn icon color='grey' @click="afegiralcarret(item.id)"> <v-icon> mdi-cart</v-icon></v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</v-col>
```